# How to create draggable component to chose year in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, mouseevent, draggable

I need to create draggable component in React (Without help any library). Below i've added photo how it might looks.
Now, my component looks:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IYearBar } from './YearBar.model';
import { 
  StyledYear, 
  StyledYearBar 
} from './YearBar.styled';

const YearBar = ({ year }: IYearBar): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <StyledYearBar>
      <StyledYear className="second"> {year - 2} </StyledYear>
      <StyledYear className="first"> {year - 1} </StyledYear>
      <StyledYear> {year} </StyledYear>
      <StyledYear className="first"> {year + 1} </StyledYear>
      <StyledYear className="second"> {year + 2} </StyledYear>
    </StyledYearBar>
  );
};

export default YearBar;
```

I'd like to dynamically scroll through this, and if I release the mouse button, the chosen year should stay in the center. Has anyone tried to create a similar component? I would like to ask for some advice and materials that can show me how to do it. Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vy14.png)

Answer (score 0):

In essence you have two events that you care about: the drag and the release.

When the user drags, you need to drag the YearBar along with them.  You can do this by repositioning your YearBar via CSS with a negative margin-left or a CSS transform.

This drag is going to have some weird intermediates where you are halfway between two years.

When the user releases, you want to “snap” so that the nearest year is fully in view and centered.  A typical way of doing this involves calculating which year is in focus based on the width of each year and the current position.